# Problems with datetime sorting in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, html, json, datetime, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator to display a the date column of my data with the following column definition

```
{ title:"Date", field:"date", sorter: "datetime", sorterParams: { format: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", alignEmptyValues:"top", }, headerFilter:"input", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams: { outputFormat:"MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss A", invalidPlaceholder: true } },
```

With these sorterParams I get no sorting (and no error message). If I try the moment.js predefined format "DATETIME_LOCAL_MS" I get some sorting, but it's not correctly parsing the dates.

I read https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/1256 so I stopped trying to make the sorterParam format match the formatterParams.

My raw data dates look like this

```
"date":"2021-03-08T15:41:29.000Z"
```

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: read on https://tabulator.info/docs/5.4/sort#sorter-datetime requires luxon.js, this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me. Please supply an actual set of data that doesn't work.

```js
var data = [
    {name:"Tom",   date:"2021-03-14T15:09:26.000Z"},
    {name:"Dick",  date:"2021-10-21T21:17:29.000Z"},
    {name:"Harry", date:"2021-11-30T02:01:29.000Z"},
    {name:"Larry", date:"2021-10-21T19:55:29.000Z"},
    {name:"Moe",   date:""},
    {name:"Curly", date:"2021-08-01T14:11:29.000Z"}
];

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
//    data:data,
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Date", field:"date", sorter: "datetime", sorterParams: { format: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", alignEmptyValues:"top", }, headerFilter:"input", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams: { outputFormat:"MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss A", invalidPlaceholder: true } },
    ],
});
table.setData(data);
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.9.3/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="example-table"></div>
```